# VBA create a reference dictionary for acronyms

Tags: vba, excel

I am implementing a really useful code that calculates the degree of similarity between two columns. Example: Column one contains "ABC Company" and Column 2 contains "ABCD Company". The VBA code will then return that column 1 and column 2 are 99% similar. This works great!

My Question/Issue: Now I would like to add some code that recognizes acronyms or treats two words as the same. Example: If Column 1 contains "ABC LLC" and Column 2 contains "ABC Limited Liability Company", I would like the code to recognize that "LLC" and "Limited Liability Company" are actually the same thing. Can I define this in a dictionary or set these two things equal to each other somehow?? Thanks! The code I was to add to is listed below

```
Public Function Similarity(ByVal String1 As String, _
                           ByVal String2 As String, _
                           Optional ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                           Optional min_match = 1) As Single

'Returns percentile of similarity between 2 strings (ignores case)

'"RetMatch"  returns the characters that match(in order)
'"min_match" specifies minimum number af char's in a row to match


Dim b1() As Byte, b2() As Byte
Dim lngLen1 As Long, lngLen2 As Long
Dim lngResult As Long

  If UCase(String1) = UCase(String2) Then       '..Exactly the same
    Similarity = 1

  Else                                          '..one string is empty
    lngLen1 = Len(String1)
    lngLen2 = Len(String2)
    If (lngLen1 = 0) Or (lngLen2 = 0) Then
      Similarity = 0

    Else                                        '..otherwise find similarity
      b1() = StrConv(UCase(String1), vbFromUnicode)
      b2() = StrConv(UCase(String2), vbFromUnicode)
      lngResult = Similarity_sub(0, lngLen1 - 1, _
                                 0, lngLen2 - 1, _
                                 b1, b2, _
                                 String1, _
                                 RetMatch, _
                                 min_match)
      Erase b1
      Erase b2
      If lngLen1 >= lngLen2 Then
        Similarity = lngResult / lngLen1
      Else
        Similarity = lngResult / lngLen2
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Function

Private Function Similarity_sub(ByVal start1 As Long, ByVal end1 As Long, _
                                ByVal start2 As Long, ByVal end2 As Long, _
                                ByRef b1() As Byte, ByRef b2() As Byte, _
                                ByVal FirstString As String, _
                                ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                                ByVal min_match As Long, _
                                Optional recur_level As Integer = 0) As Long
'* CALLED BY: Similarity *  (RECURSIVE)

Dim lngCurr1 As Long, lngCurr2 As Long
Dim lngMatchAt1 As Long, lngMatchAt2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lngLongestMatch As Long, lngLocalLongestMatch As Long
Dim strRetMatch1 As String, strRetMatch2 As String

  If (start1 > end1) Or (start1 < 0) Or (end1 - start1 + 1 < min_match) _
  Or (start2 > end2) Or (start2 < 0) Or (end2 - start2 + 1 < min_match) Then
    Exit Function     '(exit if start/end is out of string, or length is too short)
  End If

  For lngCurr1 = start1 To end1        '(for each char of first string)
    For lngCurr2 = start2 To end2        '(for each char of second string)
      i = 0
      Do Until b1(lngCurr1 + i) <> b2(lngCurr2 + i)   'as long as chars DO match..
        i = i + 1
        If i > lngLongestMatch Then     '..if longer than previous best, store starts & length
          lngMatchAt1 = lngCurr1
          lngMatchAt2 = lngCurr2
          lngLongestMatch = i
        End If
        If (lngCurr1 + i) > end1 Or (lngCurr2 + i) > end2 Then Exit Do
      Loop
    Next lngCurr2
  Next lngCurr1

  If lngLongestMatch < min_match Then Exit Function 'no matches at all, so no point checking for sub-matches!

  lngLocalLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch                   'call again for BEFORE + AFTER
  RetMatch = ""
                              'Find longest match BEFORE the current position
  lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                  + Similarity_sub(start1, lngMatchAt1 - 1, _
                                   start2, lngMatchAt2 - 1, _
                                   b1, b2, _
                                   FirstString, _
                                   strRetMatch1, _
                                   min_match, _
                                   recur_level + 1)
  If strRetMatch1 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & strRetMatch1 & "*"
  Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                              And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                              And (lngMatchAt1 > 1 Or lngMatchAt2 > 1) _
                              , "*", "")
  End If

                              'add local longest
  RetMatch = RetMatch & Mid$(FirstString, lngMatchAt1 + 1, lngLocalLongestMatch)

                              'Find longest match AFTER the current position
  lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                  + Similarity_sub(lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end1, _
                                   lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end2, _
                                   b1, b2, _
                                   FirstString, _
                                   strRetMatch2, _
                                   min_match, _
                                   recur_level + 1`enter code here`)

  If strRetMatch2 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & "*" & strRetMatch2
  Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                              And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                              And ((lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end1) _
                                   Or (lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end2)) _
                              , "*", "")
  End If
                             'Return result
  Similarity_sub = lngLongestMatch

End Function
```

Comment: There exists plugins to do this kind of thing, Fuzzy Lookups.

Comment: What about `ABC Limited Liability Comp.` or `ABC ltd. liab. Company`? Should these get evaluated to `ABC Limited Liability Company` first before this gets then compared to `LLC` or do you want to have entries in your list for each of them? How would you treat the word `spellchecker` which contains **llc** in the middle? Do you want to have a context analysis as well (evaluating spaces in between)? How would you then go about `ABC ltd.liab. Comp`? Do you also have non-US companies? Would `ABC LLC` and `ABC OOO` be the same? If ABC LLC had a branch in Russia then it would be `OOO` and not `LLC`.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes I've tried the fuzzy lookup add-in. However, I am running hundreds of thousands of records which ends up crashing the plugin before completion

Comment: @Ralph I believe I would need to use context analysis to evaluate the spaces to mitigate this issue. I have a table already created with about 80 acronyms that will need to be recognized. So I not only would need to convert "LLC" to "limited liability company", but also things like "ltd. liab. company" to "limited liability company"

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the easiest thing to do:

```
If str = "LLC" then
    str.replace("LLC","Limited Liability Company")
end if
```

Put it in a foreach, with two lists and look for something to change. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckMe()

    Dim ListA       As Collection
    Dim ListB       As Collection
    Dim str         As String
    Dim strResult   As String

    Dim varStr      As Variant
    Dim var         As Variant
    Dim varAdd      As Variant

    Dim counter     As Variant

    str = "LiLaCa is a AnAtBaa company"
    strResult = ""

    Set ListA = New Collection
    Set ListB = New Collection

    ListA.Add ("LLC")
    ListA.Add ("AAB")
    ListA.Add ("BBA")

    ListB.Add ("LiLaCa")
    ListB.Add ("AnAtBaa")
    ListB.Add ("BuBuAaaaaa")

    varStr = Split(str)

    For Each var In varStr
        varAdd = var
        For counter = 1 To ListB.Count
            If var = ListB(counter) Then varAdd = Replace(var, ListB(counter), ListA(counter))
        Next counter
        strResult = strResult & varAdd & " "
    Next var

    Debug.Print strResult

End Sub
```